# get partial sum of values in df column once they reach a certain threshold

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to start adding values in one of the columns in my df and return a row where the sum reaches a certain threshold. What is the easiest way to do it?

e.g.

```
threshold = 86

    values    ID
1   42       xxxxx
2   34       yyyyy
3   29       vvvvv
4   28       eeeee
```

should return line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(values=[42, 34, 29, 28], ID=['x', 'y', 'z', 'e']))

threshold = 86

idx = df['values'].cumsum().searchsorted(threshold)
print(df.iloc[idx])
```

[Try it here](https://repl.it/repls/SteelblueMustyEllipse)

Output:

```
values    29
ID         z
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

Note that `df.values` has a special pandas meaning so `df['values']` is different and necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
df['new_values'] = df['values'].cumsum()

rows = df[df['new_values']==threshold].index.to_list()
```

Comment: What is `to_add`? There has to be a cumulative sum or some kind of rolling operation going on.

Comment: The value you want to add

Comment: They are adding values in the DF itself. It's not some figure to hand. "I need to start adding values in one of the columns" - it's a `cumsum`

Comment: yes, roganjosh is right, what I need is a cumsum, the solution by Alex Hall works fine

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
df['values'].cumsum().ge(threshold).idxmax()

Out[131]: 3

df.loc[df['values'].cumsum().ge(threshold).idxmax()]

Out[133]:
values       29
ID        vvvvv
Name: 3, dtype: object
```